# Postgres JSONB object filtering

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a Postgres table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE products(
   id string,
   attributes jsonb,
   PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

An example of attributes field could be like:

```
 {
      "endDate": [
        "2024-02-20T21:00:00.000Z"
      ],
      "countries": [
        "US","IT","ES"
      ],
      "type": [
        "RETAIL"
      ],
      "startDate": [
        "2024-02-13T08:00:00.000Z"
      ],
      "categories": [
        "ELECTRONICS"
      ],
      "currency": [
        "USD"
      ],
      "status": [
        "ACTIVE"
      ]
    }
```

I need to create filter where as an input I might get a list of countries e.g. ["US","MX"] for which each product having one of these countries would match criteria and/or where startDate might be after certain provided date.
I'm also interested in performance of such query, since this table might be really large.

I've tried sto filter products by countries using this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE
  (attributes @> '{ "countries": ["US","MX","JP"] }')
```

But this query would list only products which have all 3 provided countries. I need to have at least one country match, and in this example, it has "US" so it should be match.

Comment: Build a proper relational model using tables instead of resorting to JSON trickery.

Comment: What query have you tried?

Comment: In your example, all json arrays have one element.  This is either a bad design, or a bad example, or both.

Comment: @jjanes I've modified example to include list of countries. Some of the subelements have only one item and I agree with you that design is bad, but it's challenging to modify it as db is shared between applications and teams.

Comment: `but it's challenging to modify it as db is shared between applications and teams. `, when that is a challenge, how do you keep your data correct? When having 25 start dates, 48 end dates and 12 statuses, you still able to see what the correct value is? To be honest, I think that nobody in all your teams is able to guarantee that the data is correct. It looks like it's just sheer luck when the data is correct and one day you will run out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be trivial on a normalised structure, but until you find time and budget to change it, you can use `jsonb` [JSONPath](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#DATATYPE-JSONPATH) expressions with [`@@` predicate check operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/5-_L1lYh)

```sql
select * from products
where attributes 
@@ '  exists($.countries[*] 
             ?(  @=="US"
               ||@=="MX" ))
    && exists($.startDate?
              (@>"2024-02-12T07:00:00.000Z"))'
;
```

| id | attributes |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"type": ["RETAIL"], "status": ["ACTIVE"], "endDate": ["2024-02-20T21:00:00.000Z"], "currency": ["USD"], "countries": ["US", "IT", "ES"], "startDate": ["2024-02-13T08:00:00.000Z"], "categories": ["ELECTRONICS"]} |

If you pair it with a [GIN index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING):

```sql
create index on products using gin(attributes jsonb_path_ops);
```

You'll see `@@` speed up significantly thanks to index scans:

|  |
| --- |
| Bitmap Heap Scan on public.products (cost=116.51..2432.07 rows=13325 width=396) (actual time=4.505..56.491 rows=9513 loops=1) |
| Output: id, attributes |
| Recheck Cond: (products.attributes @@ '(exists ($."countries"[*]?(@ == "US" || @ == "MX")) && exists ($."startDate"?(@ > "2024-02-12T07:00:00.000Z")))'::jsonpath) |
| Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 28518 |
| Heap Blocks: exact=2149 |
| -> **Bitmap Index Scan** on products_attributes_idx (cost=0.00..113.18 rows=13325 width=0) (actual time=4.238..4.239 rows=38031 loops=1) |
| Index Cond: (products.attributes @@ '(exists ($."countries"[*]?(@ == "US" || @ == "MX")) && exists ($."startDate"?(@ > "2024-02-12T07:00:00.000Z")))'::jsonpath) |
| Planning Time: 0.374 ms |
| Execution Time: 56.930 ms |

That's a test on 40k random sample resembling yours. It's also visible that not the entire JSONPath is supported by the index, hence the re-check:

> For these operators [`@@`, `@?`], a GIN index extracts clauses of the form ***accessors_chain = constant*** out of the `jsonpath` pattern, and does the index search based on the keys and values mentioned in these clauses. The accessors chain may include ***`.key`***, ***`[*]`***, and ***`[index]`*** accessors. The `jsonb_ops` operator class also supports ***`.*`*** and ***`.**`*** accessors, but the `jsonb_path_ops` operator class does not.

The part with date comparison using `>` doesn’t qualify, which is why a recheck is necessary. Searches where you don’t need the `>` should be faster.

If you're dealing with non-uniform timestamp formats, you might want to add a [`.datetime()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-OP-TABLE) method in there.

Comment: Thank you so much on great response. Would you mind giving a comment on how much of performance improvement would it be if there's an additional table product_attributes(product_id, key, value) where each product would have separate row for each attribute and each country, e.g. (p1, 'country','US'), (p1, 'country','MX')? This would also have to match by key and search multiple values. If I manage to get rid of dates here, would it be similar in performance when gin index is used, or you think normalization is still big advantage?

Comment: If you normalise, you get proper field separation and typing, and therefore adequate functions and operators, and that in turn gives you operator classes that are supported by indexes. The elegant thing about GIN index `jsob_path_ops` is that you just drop it in and you can keep your current structure but it is no match for a gang of btrees. The normalised structure will be more lightweight, the indexes will be tiny and fast to traverse - if it’s an option for you and/or you want performance, normalise.

Comment: “*How much performance*” is a good question, but a performance-focused comparison of a normalised schema to the current `jsonb` would be better off in a separate thread - I’d be happy to demo it but it would be expanding the scope of the originally posted question here. It depends on what exactly you want to fetch and based on what. If you want a short, ballpark answer, then I’d just say *much*.

Comment: Thank you for great answer. I've created another question which is related to performance and design https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78175910/postgres-data-filtering-over-attributes-performance

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the following solutions:

- Retrieve the JSON array and use array overlap comparison `?|`

```sql
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE
  attributes -> 'countries' ?| array['US', 'MX', 'JP']
```

- Use a JsonPath (you need to specify lots of conditions)

```sql
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE
  attributes @? '$.countries[*] ? (@ == "US" || @ == "MX" || @ == "JP")'
```

- Use a subquery with an `INTERSECT` against the array.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT value
  FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(attributes -> 'countries')
  INTERSECT
  SELECT *
  FROM UNNEST(array['US', 'MX', 'JP'])
)
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/iYVNKg4u)

Answer (score 1):

As Charlieface says, you could use `?|` to check that any of the given values is present.  But to get it to use an index you would need an expression index:

```
create index on products using gin ((attributes -> 'countries'));
```

But then it wouldn't work on any other keys than 'countries', so this might lead to a lot of indexes.

This index should be smaller and should be slightly more efficient than the more general index Zegarek proposed for use with the `@@` operator, but I didn't test it when anded together with conditions on startDate.